# PIC32 I2C to ADAU1761

Tags: pic

So I'm working with this part the [ADAU1761](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADAU1761.pdf) it's a little dsp codec from Analog.  I'm trying to get I2C communication up between it and my PIC32.  I spent a good part of today trying to get this to work, thinking I would verify it by reading a register.  I was getting ACKs but no data returned.  Finally I tried manually programming the ADAU1761 and then reading registers worked fine.   I'm suspicious that maybe I need to write some clock values to it first, but so far it's not too clear from the datasheet.

I am reading the datasheet and I did read their document on how to program the whole device.  I was trying to take baby steps by verifying my i2c first before trying something more advanced though.

Anyone have an experience with these parts, who might know what I need to do?

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us what you've already tried we can tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: Well I wrote routines to read and write I2C using the PIC.  Then I mucked around for hours trying to get read data back from the ADAU1761 control registers that matched a default setting.  When I manually program the ADAU1761 first using sigmadsp, the dsp comes up and works.  Now after that I get valid data back when I use the same routines to read the config registers.  So I was just wondering if anyone knew if you have to program the DSP first, maybe to get clocks and enable processor, for it to work.  I can see the transactions one my scope.

Comment: Do you have pullup resistors on your I2C lines?

Comment: Yes 2K on both lines, reads work fine after dsp is configured.  They are acked before the dsp is configured, but data is all zeros.

Answer (score 1):

For future folks, it turns out that you do have to program the ADAU1761 completely first before you can read registers.  I got it working after talking to some people at Analog and borrowing a Logic Analyzer.